# How to pass single quote to the exec.Command on Go lang

Tags: go, kubernetes

When I type `kubectl run my-release-kafka-client --restart='Never' --image docker.io/bitnami/kafka:2.7.0-debian-10-r68 --namespace default --command -- sleep infinity` on bash, it works perfectly. However, if I run through the `exec.Command()`, it says invalid restart policy. The workaround is make it `--restart=Never`. However, I'd like to know why it happens.

```golang
out, _ := exec.Command("kubectl", "run", "my-release-kafka-client", "--restart='Never'", "--image", "docker.io/bitnami/kafka:2.7.0-debian-10-r68", "--namespace", "default", "--command", "--", "sleep", "infinity").CombinedOutput()
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

*result*

```sh
error: invalid restart policy: 'Never'
See 'kubectl run -h' for help and examples
```

Comment: The single quotes are interpreted by the shell. exec.Command doesn't invoke a shell, so shell syntax doesn't apply.

Comment: Kubernetes has a [native Go SDK](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/) and using that will almost always be preferable to calling `kubectl` as a subprocess.  Or, there are [Go Kafka clients](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients#Clients-Go(AKAgolang)) as well.

Comment: Thank you, @peter. That's make sense! I also don't know why shell requires the single quote. It works without it.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidMaze I''m writing an E2E testing,  the library might be the better practice. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you put something in double quote " ", it is considered as string. So when you give "--restart='Never'" then the final value will be --restart='Never' not --restart=Never which is also pretty clear from your error message .**error: invalid restart policy: 'Never'**

That's why kubectl is looking for restartPolicy 'Never' instead of Never. That's the reason of your error message.

Comment: Thank you, Pulak. However, interesting thing is, --restart='Never' works on bash. That command is directed by bitnami kafka chart.  Also this is the help of the `kubectl run --help `      `--restart='Always': The restart policy for this Pod.  Legal values [Always, OnFailure, Never].`